# How do I use exit() correctly in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm working on a project where I want the user to be able to exit the program at any time by typing "exit" into an input field, but every time I call exit() there is additional unwanted output from the rest of the code on the console.

Here's some sample code that I wrote up:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Addition. Enter 'exit' to exit." << endl;
    string extfunc = "exit";
    float a, b, c;
    cout << "First number: "; cin >> a;
    if (to_string(a) == extfunc) {
        cout << "Exiting...";
        exit(0);
    }
    cout << "Second number: "; cin >> b;
    if (to_string(b) == extfunc) {
        cout << "Exiting...";
        exit(0);
    }
    c = a + b;
    cout << "The sum is " << c << ".";
}
```

When running this for the first I expected that when I typed "exit" for the first input that the the first if statement would go into effect but instead I got the following console output:
[The console output. This was followed by the file path and exit code 0.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxtzP.png)
Why does it also print the "Second Number" input and then jump straight to some weird sum? I'm new to this language and coding in general so perhaps there's something less obvious to me that I did wrong here.

Comment: When you convert a `float` to a string, it will be a string that represents the `float` value. What you want, I would guess, is to read a string from `cin`, and see if the string matches `"exit"`. And if not, try to convert it into a `float`.

Comment: Is it clear to you that a number can never be equal to `"exit"`?  You have made `a` a `float`.  A `float` can only hold numbers.  And whatever number it is holding, it is not going to equal the string `"exit"`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, [don't post texts as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4298200). Please make sure that any textual information is actually provided in text form.

Comment: The correct answer is you shouldn't really use `exit()` at all. It will not cleanup resources. It is better to throw an exception and handle that exception at the end of main. This allows all callstacks to unwind, destructors of objects to be called. Imagine your code is controlling a motor and you switched it on, now if you use exit it will never be switched off. If you have a motor class that will always turn off the motor when it is destructured then in the "exception" case it will be shut down, but in the "exit" case it keeps running.

Answer (score 5):

`cin >> a` reads input into a `float` variable `a`, therefore whatever you type in ***must*** be a valid floating point value.

It is true that, afterwards, you used `to_string` to convert the ***numeric*** variable `a` to a string and compare it to `"exit"`.

However that doesn't mean that it is suddenly possible to type `"exit"` and store this text into a `float` variable, such as `a`. C++ does not work this way. The input, no matter what happens to it *afterwards*, ***must*** be a floating point value. Full stop.

Instead, the correct way to do this is to use `std::getline()` to read the input into a `std::string`, and then simply compare the string to `"exit"`.

If the string is not `"exit"`, then convert it into a `float` value. There are several ways to do this in C++, such as using `std::from_chars()`, or using `std::stof()`, or using `std::istringstream` and `operator>>`, or using C library functions like `sscanf()` to `atof()`. You can use whatever means you've already learned from your C++ class/textbook to do that.